# Finding unique first letters from two columns in a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have "firstname" and "lastname" stored in a users table.

I am trying to build a list of letters A-Z and know, for each letter, whether there is at least one user with either their first letter beginning with that letter or not. The ideal output of the query would just be A,B,C,D,E,I,O,U for example although happy to post process.

I can do this easily enough on one column:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), LEFT(firstname, 1) FROM users GROUP BY LEFT(firstname, 1)
```

but that's just one column and I would like to do it for two columns. Also, if there is a more efficient way to do this - I would love to know.

Answer (score 3):

If you want data from two columns, you should use a UNION:

```
SELECT LEFT(firstname, 1)
  FROM users
 UNION
SELECT LEFT(lastname, 1)
  FROM users
```

The UNION operator selects distinct values by default, so you should not need to use DISTINCT in your SELECT statements.

Answer (score 2):

For a combined count, try:

```
select count(*), letter from
(select LEFT(firstname, 1) letter from users UNION ALL
 select LEFT(lastname, 1) letter from users)
group by letter
```

For separate counts, try:

```
select sum(firstname_count), sum(lastname_count), letter from
(select LEFT(firstname, 1) letter, 1 firstname_count, 0 lastname_count from users 
 UNION ALL
 select LEFT(lastname, 1) letter, 0 firstname_count, 1 lastname_count from users)
group by letter
```

Comment: Thanks very much; I see how that works. My ideal solution would be to avoid subqueries just because this will not be run against an index; but if that's not possible - this will do it.

Comment: Can one do function-based indexes in MySQL? If so it might be worth it in this case. If not then it might be worthwhile to add a column storing only the 1st initial and update that via trigger.